# Axis 1.x service error: No scheme found in URI

Tags: wsdl, websphere, schema, axis

I'm preparing some service using Apache Axis 1.4. So far I've generated Java classes using WSDL file (with IntelliJ), prepared server-config.wsdd file and deploy service on Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.18.

When I hit http://localhost:9081/MyService/services/SmsNotification in browser, I get:

[image]

but when I invoke service using SoapUI, I'm getting the following error:

```
org.apache.axis.types.URI$MalformedURIException: No scheme found in URI.
```

What could cause this error?

server-config.wsdd:

```
<!-- Use this file to deploy some handlers/chains and services -->
<!-- Two ways to do this: -->
<!-- java org.apache.axis.client.AdminClient deploy.wsdd -->
<!-- after the axis server is running -->
<!-- or -->
<!-- java org.apache.axis.utils.Admin client|server deploy.wsdd -->
<!-- from the same directory that the Axis engine runs -->

<deployment xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">

    <!-- Services from SmsNotificationService WSDL service -->

    <service name="SmsNotification" provider="java:RPC" style="rpc" use="literal">
        <parameter name="wsdlTargetNamespace" value="http://www.csapi.org/wsdl/parlayx/sms/notification/v1_0/service" />
        <parameter name="wsdlServiceElement" value="SmsNotificationService" />
        <parameter name="schemaUnqualified" value="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/common/v1_0,http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/v1_0" />
        <parameter name="wsdlServicePort" value="SmsNotification" />
        <parameter name="className" value="org.csapi.www.wsdl.parlayx.sms.notification.v1_0.service.SmsNotificationBindingSkeleton" />
        <parameter name="wsdlPortType" value="SmsNotification" />
        <parameter name="typeMappingVersion" value="1.2" />
        <parameter name="allowedMethods" value="*" />

        <typeMapping xmlns:ns="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/common/v1_0" qname="ns:EndUserIdentifier"
            type="java:org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.common.v1_0.EndUserIdentifier" serializer="org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializerFactory"
            deserializer="org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializerFactory" encodingStyle="" />
        <typeMapping xmlns:ns="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/common/v1_0" qname="ns:ApplicationException"
            type="java:org.csapi.www.schema.parlayx.common.v1_0.ApplicationException" serializer="org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializerFactory"
            deserializer="org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializerFactory" encodingStyle="" />
    </service>

    <transport name="http">
        <requestFlow>
            <handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.http.URLMapper" />
        </requestFlow>
    </transport>
</deployment>
```

web.xml mapping:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AdminServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AdminServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

EDIT:

Here's some logging when I call service:

```
[11.11.2021 9:05:50:752 CET] 00000139 SystemOut     O [DEBUG] (ProjectResourceBundle.java: [org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle:handleGetObject:72]) org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(popHandler00)
[11.11.2021 9:05:50:752 CET] 00000139 SystemOut     O [DEBUG] (DeserializationContext.java: [org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext:popElementHandler:829]) Popping handler org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer@f243ae8d
[11.11.2021 9:05:50:753 CET] 00000139 SystemOut     O [DEBUG] (DeserializationContext.java: [org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext:endElement:1106]) Popped element stack to org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement:senderAddress
[11.11.2021 9:05:50:753 CET] 00000139 SystemOut     O [DEBUG] (DeserializationContext.java: [org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext:endElement:1107]) Exit: DeserializationContext::endElement()
[11.11.2021 9:05:50:753 CET] 00000139 SystemOut     O [DEBUG] (ProjectResourceBundle.java: [org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle:handleGetObject:72]) org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(toAxisFault00)
[11.11.2021 9:05:50:797 CET] 00000139 SystemOut     O [DEBUG] (JavaProvider.java: [org.apache.axis.enterprise:invoke:332]) Mapping Exception to AxisFault
org.apache.axis.types.URI$MalformedURIException: No scheme found in URI.
    at org.apache.axis.types.URI.initialize(URI.java:653)
    at org.apache.axis.types.URI.<init>(URI.java:311)
    at org.apache.axis.types.URI.<init>(URI.java:272)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.makeBasicValue(SimpleDeserializer.java:324)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.makeValue(SimpleDeserializer.java:209)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onEndElement(SimpleDeserializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializerImpl.endElement(DeserializerImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:171)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.__handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:40020)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
[11.11.2021 9:05:50:807 CET] 00000139 SystemOut     O [DEBUG] (SOAPPart.java: [org.apache.axis.SOAPPart:<init>:182]) Enter: SOAPPart ctor(FORM_FAULT)
[11.11.2021 9:05:50:808 CET] 00000139 SystemOut     O [DEBUG] (ProjectResourceBundle.java: [org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle:handleGetObject:72]) org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(setMsgForm)
[11.11.2021 9:05:50:808 CET] 00000139 SystemOut     O [DEBUG] (SOAPPart.java: [org.apache.axis.SOAPPart:setCurrentForm:374]) Setting current message form to: FORM_FAULT (currentMessage is now org.apache.axis.AxisFault)
[11.11.2021 9:05:50:808 CET] 00000139 SystemOut     O [DEBUG] (SOAPPart.java: [org.apache.axis.SOAPPart:<init>:188]) Exit: SOAPPart ctor()
[11.11.2021 9:05:50:810 CET] 00000139 SystemOut     O [DEBUG] (ProjectResourceBundle.java: [org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle:handleGetObject:72]) org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(axisFault00)
[11.11.2021 9:05:50:812 CET] 00000139 SystemOut     O [DEBUG] (AxisServlet.java: [org.apache.axis.EXCEPTIONS:processAxisFault:386]) AxisFault:
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.apache.axis.types.URI$MalformedURIException: No scheme found in URI.
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.apache.axis.types.URI$MalformedURIException: No scheme found in URI.
    at org.apache.axis.types.URI.initialize(URI.java:653)
    at org.apache.axis.types.URI.&lt;init&gt;(URI.java:311)
    at org.apache.axis.types.URI.&lt;init&gt;(URI.java:272)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.makeBasicValue(SimpleDeserializer.java:324)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.makeValue(SimpleDeserializer.java:209)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onEndElement(SimpleDeserializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializerImpl.endElement(DeserializerImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:171)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.__handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:40020)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:mycompany-ro-02

org.apache.axis.types.URI$MalformedURIException: No scheme found in URI.
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:333)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.__handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:40020)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: org.apache.axis.types.URI$MalformedURIException: No scheme found in URI.
    at org.apache.axis.types.URI.initialize(URI.java:653)
    at org.apache.axis.types.URI.<init>(URI.java:311)
    at org.apache.axis.types.URI.<init>(URI.java:272)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.makeBasicValue(SimpleDeserializer.java:324)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.makeValue(SimpleDeserializer.java:209)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onEndElement(SimpleDeserializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializerImpl.endElement(DeserializerImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:171)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
```

Comment: I suppose that you're using SoapUI to hit the address you mentioned: http://localhost:9081/MyService/services/SmsNotification right? Does the stack for the failure show what URI it's failing to find the scheme in?

Comment: @ThomasJohnson Yes, I'm using SoapUI. I've added some logging in my post if it helps.

Comment: My apologizes for the delay, I just saw your reply. If you're still having issues with this, I think it's due to this URI: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:mycompany-ro-02. It looks like the SOAPUI request being received by the service provider has a junk value.